# time.Sleep sleeps for incorrect time on a VM

Tags: go

I am running the following code: https://play.golang.org/p/5bhXs_QulH

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"time"
)

func main() {
    startTime := time.Now()
    foo := 0.200
    fmt.Println(int((time.Now().UnixNano() - startTime.UnixNano()) / int64(time.Millisecond)))
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(foo*1000) * time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Println(int((time.Now().UnixNano() - startTime.UnixNano()) / int64(time.Millisecond)))
}
```

When I run it on my laptop or the playground I get:

```
0
200
```

But when I run it on a Virtual Machine (VM) I get:

```
0
anything between 150 - 250
```

I am not 100% sure which infrastructure the VM is allocated on but it is an Enterprise infrastructure for the entire company and I think it is VMWare.

Could anyone explain the difference in measurements between a physical machine and a virtual one and how to overcome it and get a consistent sleep time?

Comment: Your laptop is dedicated hardware that is always running. A VM is not necessarily always running. Other VMs are competing for limited resources. When the infrastructure detects your program blocking, it could possibly put the VM to sleep or context switch, which would take it's own amount of time to wake or context switch back to.

Comment: Use the Time methods or time.Since to compare times in go1.9 which will use monotonic times to increase the accuracy (though that still can't take into account the VM not experiencing real time)

Comment: @JimB I tried that and it didn't help.

Answer (score -2):

I eventually came up with the following:

```
func SleepMilliseconds(duration int, limit int) {
   startTime := time.Now()
   tempDuration := duration
   for {
      tempDuration = tempDuration / 2
      time.Sleep(time.Duration(tempDuration) * time.Millisecond)
      elapsed := int((time.Now().UnixNano() - startTime.UnixNano()) / int64(time.Millisecond))
      tempDuration = duration - elapsed
      if tempDuration < limit {
          break
      }
  }
}
```

**Disclaimer: I don't think this is a proper solution nor am I going to use it in my project, I just put it here in the rare case where your life (or production env) is dependent on an immediate solution and you don't know what else to do.**